# Convert a JDE Julian Date (CYYDDD) to YYYY-MM-DD format in XSLT or SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, xslt, soa, julian-date

I have a condition where I need to convert a JDE Julian Date (`CYYDDD`) to `YYYY-MM-DD` format in XSLT. Can anyone help with either some SQL query or any other way that we can do it XSLT.

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post an example of your input and the expected output. I doubt very much it's a "julian date". Who uses Julian dates in a database? Perhaps it's a Julian day number? Also state if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Hi Micheal, we are integrating JDE to thirdparty service so we have julian date in JDE tables and we need to convert that date and send it to thirdparty service in YYYY-MM-DD format. below is the information. JulinaDate: 117175 and result: 2017-06-24.  Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Here's one for JDE EnterpriseOne in SQL (as your post's tagged); will amend for XSLT before posting as an answer: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JohnLBevan/65eda22a8550c8c26b6b

Comment: @Gnaneshwar **1.** What you have is not a Julian date, but a date in a `CYYDDD` format. Some people call this the *JD Edwards Julian date*, for no good reason that I can see. **2.** You still did not say if your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k FYI: J.D.Edwards themselves called that date format a Julian Date, hence anyone working with JDE would call it that.  So whilst it's not a Julian date in the strictest sense, it is the correct term.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I am not working with JDE and the JD Edwards company is not an authority on date terminology. The term *Julian date* is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions for dealing with JDE Julian Dates (which differ from the official definition a Julian date).  For JDE:

- The units, tens & hundreds part of the number refers to days since the start of the year; with `'001'` corresponding to `1st January`.
- Everything in the thousands and above corresponds to the year; with `100` representing the year `2000`.
- Example: `100001` is `2000-01-01`

Both solutions below work in the same way:

- Date divided by 1000 & result floored (rounded down) gives the year part of the number (i.e. custs off the last 3 digits).  e.g. `123321` => `123`.
- Adding 1900 to this gives us the actual year.  e.g. `123 + 1900` => `2023`
- We then convert this to a valid date by building up a date string for 1st Jan and converting the string to a date; e.g. `2023` -> `2023-01-01`.
- Date modulus 1000 returns the days offset part of the figure (i.e. essentially cuts off all but the last 3 digits).  e.g. `123321` => `321`.
- We take 1 from the days offset (i.e. because `1st Jan` is `001`; not `000`).  e.g. `321` => `320`
- We then offset our 1st Jan date calculated from the year part by the number of days from the day part.  e.g. `2023-01-01 + 320 days` => `2023-11-17`

## MS SQL

```sql
create function dbo.ConvertJulianToDate (
    @JulianDate integer
)
returns date 
begin
    return dateadd(
       day
       , @JulianDate % 1000 - 1
       ,cast(
           cast(
               @JulianDate / 1000 + 1900 
               as varchar(4)
           ) + '-01-01' 
           as date
       )
    ) 
end
```

**Example Usage**

```sql
select dbo.ConvertJulianToDate(117175)
```

## XSLT 2.0

```xsl
<xsl:template name="JulianToDate">
    <xsl:param name="JulianDate" select="./text()" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="1900 + floor(($JulianDate div 1000))" />
    <xsl:variable name="days" select="($JulianDate mod 1000) - 1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(concat($year,'-01-01')) + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P',$days,'D'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Full Code**

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Root>
            <CallOnCurrentElement>
                <xsl:call-template name="JulianToDate" />
            </CallOnCurrentElement>
            <PassValue>
                <xsl:call-template name="JulianToDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="JulianDate">114026</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </PassValue>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="JulianToDate">
        <xsl:param name="JulianDate" select="./text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="1900 + floor(($JulianDate div 1000))" />
        <xsl:variable name="days" select="($JulianDate mod 1000) - 1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(concat($year,'-01-01')) + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P',$days,'D'))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Sample XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<julianDate>117175</julianDate>
```

Fiddle Demo: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCU

## XSLT 1.0

Date functions aren't available in XSLT 1.0, so it's very hacky.  However I believe this should work.

```
    <xsl:template name="JulianToDate">
        <xsl:param name="JulianDate" select="./text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="1900 + floor(($JulianDate div 1000))" />
        <xsl:variable name="days" select="($JulianDate mod 1000)" />
        <xsl:variable name="isLeapYear" select="(($year mod 4) = 0) and ((($year mod 100) != 0) or (($year mod 400) = 0))" />
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="febDays">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$isLeapYear">29</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>28</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="31 >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(31 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days -31" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="2" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(63 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (31 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="3" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(92 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (63 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="4" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(123 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (92 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="5" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(153 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (123 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="6" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(184 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (153 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="7" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(215 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (184 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="8" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(245 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (215 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="9" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(276 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (245 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="10" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(306 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (276 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="11" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(337 + $febDays) >= $days">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dd" select="$days - (306 + $febDays)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="MM" select="12" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="yyyy" select="$year" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message terminate="yes">Invalid Julian Date</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="CreateDate">
        <xsl:param name="yyyy" />
        <xsl:param name="MM" />
        <xsl:param name="dd" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(10000 + $yyyy, 2),'-',substring(100 + $MM, 2),'-',substring(100 + $dd, 2))"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

(This just replaces the equivalent template from the XSLT 2.0 version; all else (version number aside) should be identical.

Comment: Thanks John. its looks great. A quick question can you please let me know why we have <PassValue> which is showing some different date. but <CallOnCurrentElement> is showing exact date for the input. I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: PassValue`s just another demo. For that one I defined the value in the XSL file rather than in the XML. Purely there for demo purposes.

Comment: Anyone wanting some Julian date related entertainment may want to read this post: https://twitter.com/Tesco/status/1143449559722594306, or this book: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39074550-humble-pi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good help, but written for MS Excel. You can convert it SQL or anything else you like though: [Converting a Julian Date](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-date-time-formulas/converting-a-julian-date-to-a-calendar-date.html)

This might help too: [Julian Calendar Help](https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help Ali. I tried this but not working in XSLT.

Comment: @Gnaneshwar Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I suspect he is using xslt 1.0, jd edwards dates are commonly found in web apps such as Peoplesoft